# Inertia Vue 3 - Sending value from child layout to parent layout and parent layout to grand parent layout

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs

I am new to inertia.js and vue.js 3. I am trying to send heading from Layout3 to Layout1 and sub_heading from Layout3 to Layout2. There is Layout2 between Layout3 and Layout1. Layout3 loads in Layout2 and Layout2 loads in Layout1. Layout1 will stay the same but Layout2 and Layout3 will be dynamic. It means, any reference of Layout2 can not be given in Layout1, same goes for Layout2.

I have spent almost a day, looking for exactly what I need, before posting my question here. In most of the blogs i studied, gives reference of Layout2 in Layout1 which does not fulfill my requirement.

Since, I am a beginner, answer with detailed example code will be highly appritiated.

**Layout 1:**

```
<template>
    <h2>{{ heading }}</h2>
    <slot />
</template>
<script setup>
    const props = defineProps({
        heading: String
    });       
</script>
```

**Layout 2:**

```
<template>
    <Layout1>
        <h3>{{ sub_heading }}</h3>
        <slot />
    </Layout1>
</template>
<script>
    import Layout1 from '@/Shared/Layouts/Layout1.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            Layout1
        }
    }

    const props = defineProps({
        sub_heading: String
    });
</script>
```

**Layout 3:**

```
<template>
    <Layout2>
          <p>Languages</p>
    </Layout2>
</template>
<script>
    import Layout2 from '@/Shared/Layouts/Layout2.vue';
    import { ref, inject, computed } from 'vue';
    
    export default {
        components: {
            Layout2
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood You correctly try with [provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#app-level-provide) :

```js
const { ref, provide , inject } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const titleAsProvide = ref('Title')
    const subHeadingAsProp = ref('Sub heading')
    provide('providedTitle', titleAsProvide)
    return { subHeadingAsProp }
  },
})
app.component('Layout1', {
  template: `
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <slot />
  `,
  setup() {
    const title = inject('providedTitle')
    return { title }
  }
})
app.component('Layout2', {
  template: `
    <Layout1>
      <h3>{{ sub_heading }}</h3>
      <slot />
    </Layout1>
  `,
  props: ['sub_heading']
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <Layout2 :sub_heading="subHeadingAsProp">
    <p>Languages</p>
  </Layout2>
</div>
```